# Convert(ASSIGN) a FILE * or HANDLE to IStream in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

Want to write a function which would expect an open HANDLE to a file and
 convert it to IStream for some purposes to interact with an Wrapper library

One way i know is , I can get a FILE * from HANDLE , 
 But i am not getting any method to convert or assign this FILE * or the HANDLE directly to IStream (COM) .

Comment: That's basically asking how to implement an interface in COM. Have you read any of the tutorials and examples out there?

Comment: Yes i have gone to through the Tutorial for IStream , but there was no way i could find to convert(assign) an opened FILE * or an Opened HANDLE to IStream @Ulrich Eckhardt

Comment: Converting or assigning won't work. `IStream` is a COM interface, which should be implemented by an object. A `HANDLE` is just some number assigned by the OS, and typically just a index into a kernel-level table.

Comment: Ok @MSalters , so Can u suggest me some way , i can get a FILE * from the HANDLE by _open_osfhandle , and can any operation be done on that FILE * to be done to get it .

Comment: @ash123: You should have been able to figure that out yourself: a `FILE*`  is just a pointer to some C library internal structure, defined about 25 years before `IStream`.

Comment: Look at the sources for `_open_osfhandle()`. It takes a `HANDLE` and creates(!!!) a `FILE*` that communicates via this handle. Should be easy to write a similar function, only that it creates an `IStream`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is done, i modified the interface to work with open file handles instead of IStream

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [get filename from HANDLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx) and then [create IStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759864(v=vs.85).aspx) from the path.

Comment: yeah , i had  implemented that, but basically the file is nt yet present on disk anyways i got the solution for it,. thankyou @Eugene